# Unable to set image in background of UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to put image in background of UIView.
Problem is that my view(subView) is inside the main view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple as:

```
yourSubView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundImage.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Class:

```
@interface abc : UIView {
.......
}
```

In class define subview:

```
IBOutlet UIView* subView;
```

set background image of subView as:

```
UIColor* bgrColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed: backgroundImageName]];
subView.backgroundColor = bgrColor;
```

Finally add subview to the View

```
[self.view addSubView:subView];
```